# Failed to initialize an AVAssetExportSession (iPhone XS, XR, XMax)

Tags: avasset, avassetexportsession, avcomposition

When I instantiate an AVAssetExportSession object in new simulators instance with either of the 2 methods:

```
AVAsset *videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
AVAssetExportSession *exporter =  [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
```

or

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
```

and, run the app on one of the 3 new simulators: iPhone XR, iPhone XS, and iPhone XS MAX, I got `exporter = nil`, whereas on all other simulators I got a normal non null exporter object.

I also noticed that ONLY when I set the `presetName` parameter to be `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`, the exporter is not nil. Any other presetName will make the initialization to fail.

Anyone has encountered the similar problems?

Comment: Did you try look it up on a real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's an apple bug... https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=44701489
Will report back once the original bug is closed.

EDIT: This issue has been fixed by Apple in iOS 10.1 SDK. You just update your xcode to 10.1.